# ReactJs 18.2 view not rendering properly despite useState successfully updating data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component that generates a series of  elements based on an array called game_letters, whose length is determined by another array, letter_of_rec that contains a varying number of letters.  When a user enters a letter, a function compares the entered letter to the same index in letter_of_rec to see if there is a match, and if there is then that value is entered in the same position in game_letters.

I have another function, AdLetter, that, if the user clicks a button, enters a random letter in game_letters. The issue is that when the state is updated in the AdLetter function, the letters appear in the inputs whereas when a user enters a letter, including those entered by the user.

When the user enters a letter, though the state is set as in AdLetter, no letters appear.

NOTE-The array that populates the inputs is being correctly updated by useState. I'm simply the change onscreen unless I click "Add Letter."

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';



const Word: React.FC = () => {

  const [game_letters, setGameLetters] = useState<GameLetter[]>([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    getGameLetterArray(letter_of_rec.length);
  }, [letter_of_rec]);

 
  const getGameLetterArray=(length:number)=>{
    const workArray:GameLetter[] = [];
    for(let i=0; i<length;i++) {
      let key:number = genRandNum(1000);
         workArray.push({key:key, val:"", needsTrans:false});
     }
   
     setGameLetters(workArray);
    
  }

  function adLetter(){  
     let indexArray = rtnIdxArray(game_letters);
     console.log("array of available indexes is ");
     console.log(indexArray);
     let len = indexArray.length;
    let rand = genRandNum(len);
    let letterToAdd = letter_of_rec[rand];
    const workArray:GameLetter[] = rtnArrayWithVal(game_letters,rand,letter_of_rec[rand]);
    setGameLetters(workArray);
   // console.log(letter_of_rec);
   }


  const onHandleAttempt = (index: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(event.target.value))
    {
       let attempt = event.target.value;
        letter_of_rec.forEach((val,idx)=>{    
      if(letter_of_rec[idx]===attempt){
          
           updateGameLetter(attempt,idx);  
           console.log("game letters");
           console.log(game_letters)
               
        }
     });
    }
     
  };

   
  const updateGameLetter = (val:string, index:number)=>{
    //console.log("update Game letter index "+val);
    //console.log("update Game letter index "+index)
    if(letter_of_rec[index]===val){    
       const workArray:GameLetter[] = game_letters;
       console.log("workarray");
       console.log(workArray);
       workArray[index].val=val;
       setGameLetters(workArray);
       console.log("game letters after update");
       console.log(game_letters);
    }
    

    //console.log("work array is "+workArray);
   
  };  


  

  
  return (
    <div className='wordWrapper'>
        <p>{word}</p>
        <p>{word.length}</p>
      <div className="letter_box">
  

 
             
  {game_letters.length > 0 && // Add a conditional check here
          game_letters.map((letter, idx) => {
            return (
              <input
                key={letter.key}
                value={letter.val}
                onChange={(e) => onHandleAttempt(idx, e)}
              />
            );
          })
    }
              <Hint truWordId={wordId} hintList={hints}></Hint>
            
        
      </div>
       
      <div className='gameButtonBox'>
          <button onClick={adLetter}>Add Letter</button>
         <button onClick={newGame} >New Game</button>
         <button onClick={removeHint} >Need hint</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
   
  ); 
};

export default Word;
```

Comment: Where is letter_of_rec defined? prop, state?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the issue is with this line: `const workArray:GameLetter[] = game_letters;`. Try making a deep copy of `game_letters`, like this `const workArray:GameLetter[] = [...game_letters];`

Comment: The array itself is being updated correctly. The issue is that I'm not seeing the change in the inputs when the user inputs the data, only when they click the "Add User" button.